# Dropzone.js transformFile function for resizing images

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, dropzone.js, stimulusjs

I have implemented a drag and drop image upload with Dropzone.js in my Rails app following this tutorial: https://web-crunch.com/posts/rails-drag-drop-active-storage-stimulus-dropzone

Now I also want to resize the images to a maximum width before they are uploaded. Dropzone.js has a `transformFile` function for this purpose but I haven't managed to make it work. I have tried the following.

When I create the dropzone element, I declare a maximum width (`resizeWidth`):

```
function createDropZone(controller) {
  return new Dropzone(controller.element, {
    url: controller.url,
    headers: controller.headers,
    maxFiles: controller.maxFiles,
    maxFilesize: controller.maxFileSize,
    acceptedFiles: controller.acceptedFiles,
    addRemoveLinks: controller.addRemoveLinks,
    resizeWidth: 200,
    autoQueue: false
  });
}
```

Then, I call the function `transformFile` inside an `addedfile` event listener:

```
this.dropZone.on("addedfile", file => {
      this.dropZone.options.transformFile(file);
      
      setTimeout(() => {
        file.accepted && createDirectUploadController(this, file).start();
      }, 500);
    });
```

However, the response on the console is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'resizeWidth' of undefined`

Could anybody help me?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

The error encountered is because the `this` inside the `transformFile` function is not bound to the correct context in this example. To get rid of the error you have to bind it back to the dropzone controller like this:

```js
const transformFile = this.dropZone.options.transformFile.bind(this.dropZone)

transformFile(file);
```

But the `transformFile` method accepts a 2nd argument which is a callback function for when the transformation is done. Here is the correct way to use it:

```js
   this.dropZone.on('addedfile', async (file) => {
      const resizeFunction = async (file) => {
        return await new Promise((resolve) => {
          // Rely on dropzone built-in resize implementation:
          const transformFile = this.dropZone.options.transformFile.bind(this.dropZone)
          transformFile(file, (transformedFile) => {
            resolve(transformedFile)
          })
        })
      }

      const resizedBlob = await resizeFunction(file)
      const resizedFile = new File([resizedBlob], file.name, { type: resizedBlob.type })

      /// .. rest of the implementation
    }
```

You will notice that this doesn't integrate nicely with dropzone's other features (like removing files), the call to resize must happen right before `new DirectUpload`, so you will have to make modifications to pass either the dropzone instance or the `resizeFunction` to `createDirectUploadController` all the way down to that point.

This is what the final call site looks like in my app:

```js
  const resizedBlob = await resizeFunction(file)
  const resizedFile = new File([resizedBlob], file.name, { type: resizedBlob.type })
  return new DirectUpload(resizedFile, url, controller)
```